# Multiple In App Purchase - How to set different ID when purchased

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

On my app, I have set up 2 different In App Purchase Ids, lets say;

com.myapp.purchase1
com.myapp.purchase2

The upgrades are set to 2 different IBActions with an alert.tag for each to differenciate between the product upgrade.
This part works fine, however.

Purchase 1 = Remove advertisements
Purchase 2 = Adds More Colors

If I purchase, Purchase 2, it works - adverts remain.
If I purchase Purchase 1, it removes adverts, and unlocks the colors as well - this is wrong.

Purchase 2 is linked to a NSUSerDefaults here;

```
-(void)randImage
{
    currentIndex = (currentIndex+1) % ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"com.myapp.purchase2"] ? 32 : 16);

        UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"f%d.png",currentIndex +1]];

        [ColorsImage setImage:myImage];

}
```

This is from MKStoreManager.h

```
#define kConsumableBaseFeatureId @"com.myapp.colorsapp"
#define kFeatureAId @"com.myapp.purchase1"
#define kFeatureBId @"com.myapp.purchase2"
```

When the upgrade process is made, this is the code, I suspect this is the problem area, but cannot think how I would fix it? I am calling the setBool after the purchase, which I guess is called even when purchase1 is made; how can I only call that when purchase2 is made?

```
-(void) provideContent: (NSString*) productIdentifier 
           forReceipt:(NSData*) receiptData
{
    if(ownServer != nil && SERVER_PRODUCT_MODEL)
    {
        // ping server and get response before serializing the product
        // this is a blocking call to post receipt data to your server
        // it should normally take a couple of seconds on a good 3G connection
        if(![self verifyReceipt:receiptData]) return;
    }

    NSRange range = [productIdentifier rangeOfString:kConsumableBaseFeatureId];     
    NSString *countText = [productIdentifier substringFromIndex:range.location+[kConsumableBaseFeatureId length]];

    int quantityPurchased = [countText intValue];
    if(quantityPurchased != 0)
    {

        int oldCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:productIdentifier];
        oldCount += quantityPurchased;  

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:oldCount forKey:productIdentifier];       
    }
    else 
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];       
    }

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(productPurchased:)])
        [_delegate productPurchased:productIdentifier];



    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"com.myapp.purchase2"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Upgrades" message:@"Successfully Purchased" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];

}
```

Comment: This sounds like a classic case of forgetting to add a "break" to a switch case in your IBAction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks quite obvious, you forgot these 2 lines in your `provideContent:forReceipt:` function. Whenever you call it, product with id `@"com.myapp.purchase2"` will be enabled. Remove these lines from your function.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"com.myapp.purchase2"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Hi Guenis! OK but if I remove those two lines from the MKStore function then where else can I put them? Because they need to be upon purchase confirmation to be enabled if a user purchases com.myapp.purchase2 ?

Comment: put an if statement to understand which product is purchased. `if([productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.myapp.purchase2"])` if this statement is not true don't unlock the content for `@"com.myapp.purchase2"]`

Comment: So would I do that in the MKStoreKit file such as;

`if([productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.myapp.purchase2"]){
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"com.myapp.purchase2"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}else{
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Upgrades" message:@"Successfully Purchased" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];`

Comment: nope. your providecontent func is for all in-app purchases right? so if `@"com.myapp.purchase2"` is purchased this function will be called? then you already enable it in else block `else 
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];       
    }` why do you need to enable it again

Comment: Hi, I think I have written it confusingly.
They are 2 separate in app purchases, the providecontent function was original just set to work with com.myapp.purchase1 however I wanted to add a second product they are separate purchases, when one is purchase it should not enable the other, the only time all is enabled, is if both have been purchased.

Comment: Would I be better just doing this for the purchase2

`-(void)randImage
{
if (![MKStoreManager isFeaturePurchased:@"com.myapp.purchase2"]) {

    currentIndex = (currentIndex+1) % ([ ? 16);

}else{

currentIndex = (currentIndex+1) % ([ ? 32);

}`
        UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"f%d.png",currentIndex +1]];

        [ColorsImage setImage:myImage];

}

Comment: i don't use mkstorekit, but you can do so it looks fine

Answer (score 0):

I think I am late for answering your question but for others they can try this [storekit](https://github.com/idzDeveloper/IDZStoreKit)
for non consumable products. It supports ios 5 and above. It also supports ios 6 hosted content and for below ios 6 devices you just have to add your server content url.

Enjoy coding! :)